# How can I restrict types based on values from an array of typed objects?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have an array of objects, and I want to restrict a function's arguments to the values of keys of those objects... would I be able to do that using Typescript?  I'd prefer to avoid creating an enum of all of the values...

```
const fonts = [
  {
    value: 'Font Name 1',
    label: 'Font Label 1',
  },
  {
    value: 'Font Name 2',
    label: 'Font Label 2',
  },
];

function doSomething(value) {
  // Do something.
}

function doSomethingElse(label) {
  // Do something.
}

doSomething('Font Name 1'); // good
doSomething('Font Name 2'); // good
doSomething('Font Name 3'); // error

doSomething('Font Label 1'); // good
doSomething('Font Label 2'); // good
doSomething('Font Label 3'); // error
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but you need to use a function when assigning `fonts` in order to help typescript infer string literal types for value and label.

Then we can use type queries to get the type of `value` and `label` which will be a union of string literal types

```
function createFonts<T extends Array<{ value: V, label: L }>, V extends string, L extends string>(...o: T) {
    return o
} 
// Type as  [{ value: "Font Name 1"; label: "Font Label 1"; }, { value: "Font Name 2"; label: "Font Label 2"; }]
const fonts = createFonts({
    value: 'Font Name 1',
    label: 'Font Label 1',
},
{
    value: 'Font Name 2',
    label: 'Font Label 2',
})

function doSomething(value: typeof fonts[number]['value']) {
// Do something.
}

function doSomethingElse(label: typeof fonts[number]['label']) {
// Do something.
}

doSomething('Font Name 1'); // good
doSomething('Font Name 2'); // good
doSomething('Font Name 3'); // error

doSomethingElse('Font Label 1'); // good
doSomethingElse('Font Label 2'); // good
doSomethingElse('Font Label 3'); // error
```

Comment: Very liked your solution. And if value and label are parts of another class or interface like:

Comment: Very liked your solution. And if value and label are parts of another class or interface like: interface MyValues{value:string; label: string;other:number}? @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir